Bouncing tags when going to new line
I noticed this today on a question. To be honest I am not completely sure what triggers it. Something along the lines of the last tag goes to the second line, but on hover, the "edit tags" link appears and the last tag jumps back up to the first line.
Here is a GIF:


Could you add a link to the question you noticed this on and what browser/OS you use? (It'll make it a bit easier to reproduce.)

@JonEricson Here is the question. It happens to me on Chrome both in Linux and OSX.

Probably the grey box is just ever so slightly larger according to the browser (or the blue box ever so slightly smaller, whichever you prefer). So when it gets selected it just fits in the line, which is treated like text, i.e. it flows over when it cannot display the box as a whole. Probably requires pixel perfect size for this ever to become a problem. Annoying anyway of course.
